# line break in alert popup

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to add a new line Javascript alert message. I tried '\n' and 'Environment.NewLine'. I am getting Unterminated string constant error. Could you please let me know what could be the problem? I appreciate any help. I also tried \r\n.

```
string msg = "Your session will expire in 10 minutes. \n Please save your work to avoid this.";


if (!this.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(ID)) 
   this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), ID, String.Format("<script language=JavaScript>setTimeout(\'alert(\"{1}\");\',{0}*1000);</script>", sTime, msg));
```

Comment: I know i posted below to add an @ in front of "string msg", but upon further review, you should probably add it in here: String.Format(@"<script...."  - or both.  If you already tried this, which line is generating the error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suspect that you need to change your code to;

```
string msg = "Your session will expire in 10 minutes. \\n Please save your work to avoid this.";
```

And escape the `\n` otherwise your code outputted would actually include the line break rather than `\n`

Your output code would look like:

```
setTimeout('alert("Your Session....
 Please save your work to ....");', 1000);
```

Rather than:

```
setTimeout('alert("Your Session....\n Please save your work to ....");', 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I think that \n is escaped in the string.Format method, like \". Maybe you should use \\n instead.

Edited : and the first \ of \\n has been escaped when i posted that. xD

Answer (score 2):

At first glance I would say the primary problem is that you're escaping the `'` character around your alert. Since your string is defined by the double quotes, you don't need to escape this character.

Comment: I tried removing ' character around alert. But I have the same issue.

Comment: @nav100: You don't remove the character, you just don't escape it. `"<script language=JavaScript>setTimeout('alert(\"{1}\"); ...`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

add "@" at the beginning of your string - like this:

```
string msg = @"Your session ....";
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, so I'm going to guess that you're using a message that itself has a `'` quote in it, causing the JS syntax error. For inserting dynamic text into a Javascript code block, you really should use JSON to make your C# strings 'safe' for use in JS.

Consider JSON the go-to method for preventing the JS equivalent of SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `@` at the beginning should help.